# Using go-kit logger api missing methods

Tags: go, factory, abstraction

I want to use the logger from [go kit](https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/log) repository and I saw that
that the author provided also [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) API/factory , while trying to test it with some common API functionality of logrus like ,`withFields` and `error` / `info` / `panic` etc
I couldn't use them only log
Any idea how can I add the missing log functionality ?

[logrus.WithField](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#fields) API.

this is what I miss

```
  log.WithFields(log.Fields{
    "animal": "walrus",
  }).Info("A walrus appears")
```

and also the info / error / debug etc

This is what I've tried

```
package main

import (
   log "github.com/go-kit/kit/log/logrus"
   "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {

   logrusLogger := logrus.New()

   logrusLogger.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{TimestampFormat: "02-01-2006 15:04:05"}
   logger := log.NewLogrusLogger(logrusLogger)

    logger.Log("hello", "world”)  //working

   logger.WithFields(    //doesnt work

    logger.Info(      //doesnt work

}
```

The logger is type `logrus` but I cannot use `withFields` OR **info/error/debug** etc, any idea what am I missing here? 
as the log kit create some factory is there a way to use the logrus api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `log.NewLogrusLogger()` creates the unexported `logruslogger` which has only one method `Log` (satisfying the `log.Logger` interface). It doesn't support the other methods from logrus itself.

This `Log` method can take arguments in key value pairs and put them in `logrus.Fields` while logging. So if you do `Log("hello", "world")`, it would set `hello` field's value to `world`. But this wouldn't work for `level` or other features.

However, since `logrus.FieldLogger` is embedded in the implementation of the `logruslogger`, we can assert our logger to behave like `logrus.FieldLogger` and then do this:

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/go-kit/kit/log/logrus"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {

    logrusLogger := logrus.New()

    logrusLogger.Formatter = &logrus.JSONFormatter{TimestampFormat: "02-01-2006 15:04:05"}
    logger := log.NewLogrusLogger(logrusLogger).(logrus.FieldLogger)

    logger.Error("Hello")
    logger.Warn("Warning you")

    logger.WithField("good", "bad").Infoln("is it good or bad?")

}
```

I hope this helps. But since they only exposed the `Log` method, there might be conscious design decisions behind those. You may keep using just `Log` or if you want more flexibility, I would suggest setting up your own logger (using logrus) instead of what I just did above. That would be a cleaner approach IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1+ you recommended to use just log(of go-kit), so what are the  benfit of the `go-kit` when they extend the `logrus` and `zap`?

Comment: I think they just provided an interface so you can connect your favorite logger with it. And that's why they had to build a very common interface and couldn't allow per logger based features. If my answer helped, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I accept the answer :-) , one question, if I want to switch between the usage of the logger sometime `zap` and sometime `logrus` I need to use just log ? nothing else , so I dont really understand the benfit here ?

Comment: If you want to switch between loggers, you will also need to initiate the respective logger. Specially here: `logger := log.NewLogrusLogger(logrusLogger)` - you would create a new ZapLogger or whatever else you want to use. With that, you will only get the `Log` method. The benefit is that you don't need to change your code anywhere. If you used logrus specific features and then switched to zap, you needed to change those. But with one common interface, you don't have to.